# Find the function $v(x,y)$ that will make $f(z) = e^xsin(y) + iv(x,y)$ analytic, and such that $f(0)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Here's what I have done so far:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = e^x\sin(y)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = e^x\cos(y)=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-e^x\cos(y)$$

So to find $v(x,y)$ do I integrate for $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ or $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ or both to find what the constant is?. I think I'm completely on the wrong track here. Or do I try to solve using harmonic functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first equation, you have 
$$\partial_y v = e^x\sin(y) \Rightarrow v = -e^x\cos(y) + A(x)$$
From the second equation, you have
$$\partial_x v = -e^x\cos(y) \Rightarrow v = -e^x\cos(y) + B(y)$$

In order for these to both be true, we need
$$A(x) = B(y) = C$$
where $C$ is a constant, independent of $x$ and $y$. Thus, we have
$$ v = C-e^x\cos(y) $$
and so,
$$ f(x+iy) = e^x\sin(y) + i(C-e^x\cos(y))$$
Substituting $z=0$ gives us
$$ f(0) = i(C-1) = 0 \Rightarrow C=1$$
and thus, the function must be
$$ f(x+iy) = e^x\sin(y)+i(1-e^x\cos(y))$$
with $$v(x,y) = 1-e^x\cos(y)$$